# How to use sops exec-file with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, podman, mozilla-sops

I can't use docker compose and sops together, I don't know why

```
sops exec-file file.env "docker compose --env-file {} up -d"
```

hangs forever, but this works:

```
sops exec-file file.env "cat {}"
```

I've tried to use Podman instead of Docker and it worked, I need to use Docker not Podman.

Comment: You are aiming this question at quite a small set of people. They need to know docker, podman AND sops. I've never heard of sops, for example. One place that might be worth investigating is behaviour around stdin/stdout/stderr - I'm assuming sops runs the command in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the option `--no-fifo` works.
It seems like Docker does not support named piped so we need to use the --no-fifo option.

```
sops exec-file --no-fifo file.env "docker compose --env-file {} up -d"
```